# IIS-Windows-Authentication stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis

I'm trying to access an old ASP.NET-Api(API 1) via Angular 8. Because of CORS-Issues the access is handled via a `proxy.conf.js`-File. (Found in another post)

```
var Agent = require("agentkeepalive");

var keepaliveAgent = new Agent({
  maxSockets: 100,
  keepAlive: true,
  maxFreeSockets: 10,
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
  timeout: 60000,
  keepAliveTimeout: 30000 // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds
});

var onProxyRes = function (proxyRes, req, res) {
  var key = 'www-authenticate';
  proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
};

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    target: Application-Url,
    context: "/api/",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    auth: "LOGIN:PASS",
    loglevel: "debug",
    onProxyRes: onProxyRes,
    agent: keepaliveAgent
  }
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

In the .NET-Application the only thing that hints to the authentification is the following line in the `web.config`-File.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

When compiled and executed the following behavior occurs:
A login-mask shows up which asks for windows-authentication. If the credentials are entered the mask closes and reopens again instantly. This behaviour continous endlessly.

Note: Accessing the api-endpoints via the commandline of the browser works perfectly fine.

Comment: Check if you hit loopback check.

Comment: How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use below PowerShell command to disable look back check:

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -Value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

after changing the registry key restarts the machine.

or you could try below things:

set this code in your web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

and make sure that you set NTML as the first provider.

[image]

check that under Advanced Settings... the Extended Protection is set to Accept.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did it actually!